# What are all of the pins of the Beaglebone Black Rev. C serial (debug) header?

Tags: serial, rs232, beaglebone-black

The Beaglebone Black Rev. C has a serial debug header with 6 pins. I would like to know what each of these pins is. If numbered 1-6 starting closer to the 5v barrel connector, pin 1 is ground, pin 4 is RX, and pin 5 is TX. What are the other pins? Are they NC (not connected)? do any supply any power? Can they safely have an applied voltage (3.3V, 5V, or other)? Consider that most FTDI cables, which match up to the Tx/Rx/Gnd header pins, have a supply voltage output that would line up with header pin 3 (as I have defined the numbering). Are the other pins functional RTS and CTS, as would match up with the FTDI connections? What are the safe/recommended voltage ranges for pins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a schematic available here: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#LATEST_PRODUCTION_FILES_.28C.29

See page 4.  Looks like J1 (the UART0 serial port) has only three of the six pins connected - ground, TX, and RX.  The others are NC, so you can apply any reasonable voltage to them.  Looks like it is designed to work with a USB to TTL serial cable.  The TX and RX signals pass through a 74LVC2G241 dual tristate non-inverting buffer/driver that is powered by the 3.3 volt supply.  The inputs are 5v tolerant.

The CTS pin of the UART is not connected while the RTS pin is brought out as TP9.

By the way, those are some of the longest pin names that I have seen.

Comment: According to Page 4 of https://github.com/CircuitCo/BeagleBone-Black/blob/master/BBB_SCH.pdf?raw=true "UART0 Serial Port USB to TTL Serial Cable 3.3V" it appears that all of the other pins are simply Not Connected. Am I reading this correctly? Also, it is my understanding that the TX and RX are only 3.3V tolerant. (The TX/RX info is easily found, but I'm just trying to get all of the information here in one place. I hadn't seen it clearly spelled out that the other pins are NC.)

Comment: That is the exact schematic that I linked.  The pins are NC and they are connected to the processor via a 5V tolerant buffer chip.  The output level will only be 3.3 volts, though, so if you use it with a 5v cable you need to make sure that the cable will read 3.3v as a logic high level (they usually do).